# Linux completely frozen

Tags: linux, fedora, freeze, data

My linux system just froze and I can't even switch to tty.
I can't force reboot it because it is moving a partiton (a HDD with no system files) with really important data which I can't afford to lose.
I even tried blindly switching to tty and writing commands but that does not work.
SSH is not configures but CUPS is,tried to use CUPS in order to see if the system can process something but no luck.
What can I do?
I use nobara 36 with KDE Plasma,no separate boot device.
No backups either,guess I gonna do them after I fix this.

Comment: What partition did you move? Maybe you move parts of the operating system or the directory you were in? Then you’ll probably have to wait until the prompt returns. Or maybe you have ssh access from a different machine?

Comment: It's from a separate HDD,no system files in it,I did not configure SSH into it but I did configure CUPS,I will try to print something from it.

Comment: Nope,it does not find the CUPS server.

Comment: You say "_it is moving a partition with really important data which I can't afford to lose_" - (1) what command or process are/were you running, and copying what partition? (2) were you running your system itself, or running from a separate boot device? (3) do you have a backup?

Comment: I use KDE Partiton manager,and I don't have a backup yet...I use the system itself, no separate boot device

Comment: ↑ please [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/721505/edit) to provide this information. Do not reply in the comments as such responses can be missed by people trying to help you. Assume comments can (and do) get deleted.

Answer (score 0):

IDK what I did,I randomly switched my HDMI cable from GPU to iGPU,blindly used tty with

> username,passwd,killall kwin

and eventually it fixed by itself,idk how but tysm for helping me.
It probably was a mesa error or something,scarry bug!